# Disabling the Codeigniter’s cache for logged in users

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching

I'm using codeigniter cache on my personal CMS. The problem is, i don't want to show cached pages if the user it's logged on administration.

Saw this tutorial on google: 
http://www.badpenguin.org/codeigniter-cache-disable

```
class MY_Output extends CI_Output {

    function _display_cache(&$CFG, &$URI)
    {
        /* Simple Test for Ip Address */
        if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == NOCACHE_IP ) 
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
        /* Simple Test for a cookie value */
        if ( (isset($_COOKIE['nocache'])) && ( $_COOKIE['nocache'] > 0 ) )
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
        /* Call the parent function */
        return parent::_display_cache($CFG,$URI);
    }
}
```

The problem it's that the session it's on database (ci_sessions), and i can't access it inside MY_Output.

using:

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->session->userdata('userID')
```

give me:

```
Class 'CI_Controller' not found in
```

As output runs before controller, and session Needs CIcontroller, the only Thing i can think of its disable session storage on database and the encription, and i don't want do that rs.

Someone can give me some light on this? i still can't find the solution to this!

Thanks!

Comment: Hm, interesting... If answer bellow doesn't help - Instead of extending CI classes, here is one interesting idea: http://goobbe.com/questions/1927427/disable-output-caching-in-codeigniter-for-logged-in-users - Basically, you can make something like 'preview' controller(s) for admin where output will not be cached, so he can preview changes he made. It is not perfect solution, but it is worth trying...

Comment: as cache loads before controller, this wont work.

Comment: Well.. The only Thing i can do is stop using db to store the cache i think...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@$SESS = & load_class('Session', 'libraries/Session');
```

The @ is there to prevent it from whining about "session already started". Do note: this is for CI3. The code for the original Output class states (lines 407-409):

```
// Note:  We use load_class() because we can't use $CI =& get_instance()
// since this function is sometimes called by the caching mechanism,
// which happens before the CI super object is available.
```

Comment: With @, gives me a blank page. And without it, the same error, Class 'CI_Controller' not found in

Comment: i found out the Session class uses the get_instance() herself on her  constructor. you can't load it if the CI object wasn't defined yet.

Comment: yeah. If it finds a cache file, will output it, and wont even load controller.